# Shell script to print text between text1 and text2 for multiple occurances

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I want to read log file which contains all the logs and some xml nodes in between.

input.log

```
logs....
logs....
This is Sample File with lots of logs and now somewhere there is start xml tag <Start> start1 
<child1>12345</child1>
<child2>67890</child2>
</Start>. Now writing 2nd start and end tags <Start> start2
<child1>54321</child1>
<child2>09876</child2>
</Start> some more logs...
logs...
logs...
logs... some other xml nodes
logs...
```

I want shell script to print below

```
<Start> start1 
<child1>12345</child1>
<child2>67890</child2>
</Start>
<Start> start2
<child1>54321</child1>
<child2>09876</child2>
</Start>
```

I followed below link and was able to get results like below
Link: https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/119502-extracting-text-between-two-unique-lines.html

```
This is Sample File with start and end tags <Start> start1 
<child1>12345</child1>
<child2>67890</child2>
</Start>. Now writing 2nd start and end tags <Start> start2
<child1>54321</child1>
<child2>09876</child2>
</Start> Ending the file content.
```

This is because it is searching for  and printing all the lines until it founds . Hence Text before  and after  appears.

I also tried using grep  command but couldn't figure out.
grep command used:
`echo "$value" | grep -oP '(?<=<Start>).*?(?=</Start>)'`

Comment: please update the question with your `awk/grep` coding attempts and the (wrong) results genearated by your code

Comment: please replace that `unix.com` link with your actual code attempt; links may disappear (in the future) and the link doesn't show us your actual code (eg, it's not clear which piece of code from that link you tried and/or whether you made any tweaks/modifications to said code)

Comment: This might work for you: `tr '\n' '\003' < input.txt | grep -Po '<Start>.*?</Start>' | tr '\003' '\n'`

Comment: Looks like you're trying to parse an XML file. Is that the case?

Comment: Place a newline before `<Start>` and after `</Start>` then filter lines between `<Start>` and `</Start>`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin - Can you please help me understand what tr command does and all those parameters that you have used ?? I haven't tried this though because I want to first understand what you are trying to do here. I'm very new to shell scripting. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If you're parsing an XML file, use an XML parser. [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) is one:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //Start -c . -n file.xml
```

Given file.xml contains

```xml
<root>
This is Sample File with start and end tags <Start> start1
<child1>12345</child1>
<child2>67890</child2>
</Start>.  Now writing 2nd start and end tags <Start> start2
<child1>54321</child1>
<child2>09876</child2>
</Start> Ending the file content.
</root>
```

then the `xmlstarlet` command outputs

```xml
<Start> start1
<child1>12345</child1>
<child2>67890</child2>
</Start>
<Start> start2
<child1>54321</child1>
<child2>09876</child2>
</Start>
```

Comment: I'm not parsing an xml file. It is an log file and i want to take out all the xml nodes ie. <Start></Start> everything containing between these tags.

Comment: If your file in not too huge, add the `-z` grep option. That makes the null byte the line ending character, so newlines are just regular characters. Then `grep -zoP '<Start>.*?</Start>'` should work